# PHP emailing JSON file

Tags: php, json

I am trying to email my json from a httppost to my site. With the following code. but it wont work. How can I email the whole JSON file to myself?

```
$myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($myString);

$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'JSON file';
$message = $json;
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Email doesn't send? Email is empty? Also, what is the purpose of this: `$ALL = $myString."\r\n";`

Comment: Shouldn't $message be a string? You are trying to send a full object! Also, unless you want JSON string in the body of the email, you can try sending it as an attachment.

Comment: Email isnt sending... I can parse the json and pull needed values from it. But when i try to send the whole JSON it wont send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode()` returns an object, and your `$message` should be a `string`. You shouldn't do anything with your `$myString` variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` returns an object. If you want to send the content by mail, you have to change it to a string. For example :

```
$message = print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are intending to send the JSON content in your email then you must not 
json_decode your input received. As the input received is the string and that only needs to be mailed as  sending object will result in the fatal error.